# How can I identify 401 and 408(timeout) error on the ionic and ios?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to connect to remote service (via ngResource) that required authentication without auth data, when I connect on android I get 401 error (it's ok), but when I connect to that service on ios I get -1 error status.

When I get timeout, I get -1 error on both systems.

How can I identify errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe currently you cannot differentiate these two errors in iOS as i could see this defect still open in official Apache Cordova Bug Tracking System.

Request you to check out this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415). Also these is a hack mentioned in the defect comments which you may try out.